# Sum two int variable in REST API

Tags: rest, elasticsearch

I want to sum two integer variable in REST API such like below:

```
"aggs": {  
    "download1" : {
        "filter" : { "term": { "IPV4_DST_ADDR":"120.127.160.91"} },
        "aggs" : {
            "downlod_bytes" : { "sum" : { "field" : "IN_BYTES" } }
        }
    },
    "download2" : {
        "filter" : { "term": { "IPV4_SRC_ADDR":"120.127.160.91"} },
        "aggs" : {
            "downlod_bytes" : { "sum" : { "field" : "OUT_BYTES" } }
        }
    },"upload1" : {
        "filter" : { "term": { "IPV4_DST_ADDR":"120.127.160.91"} },
        "aggs" : {
            "upload_bytes" : { "sum" : { "field" : "OUT_BYTES" } }
        }
    },"upload2" : {
        "filter" : { "term": { "IPV4_SRC_ADDR":"120.127.160.91"} },
        "aggs" : {
            "upload_bytes" : { "sum" : { "field" : "IN_BYTES" } }
        }
    }
}
```

add download1 to download2 and add upload1 to upload2
how can I do?

thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't mean to be a smartass, but why don't you add them on the client side?

Comment: ok, it a solution haha.